# Scraping Issue with stathead.com

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape data from stathead.com, basketball-reference.com's new subscription service. When using my normal approach that I would've used on BR, it won't scrape the first 10 rows, or 21-100 rows, only 11-20. Any thoughts? For example, stats only returns a subset of the full data.

```
url = "https://stathead.com/basketball/lineup_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&order_by_asc=0&order_by=diff_pts&lineup_type=2-man&output=per_poss&is_playoffs=N&year_id=2015&ccomp%5B1%5D=gt&cval%5B1%5D=100&cstat%5B1%5D=mp&game_month=0&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99"
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')][1:]
player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows[i].findAll('td')]
        for i in range(len(rows))]
stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)
```

Comment: You have to login to access the full results - this is a subscription service. You may be able to login using a browser and then use the login cookie through a library such as browser_cookie3 or you could also use python selenium.

Comment: as stated above, you need to login. you may be able to do that with requests Sessions

Answer (score -1):

** you can try the below code and later filter out the required data.**

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://stathead.com/basketball/lineup_finder.cgi?request=1&match=single&order_by_asc=0&order_by=diff_pts&lineup_type=2-man&output=per_poss&is_playoffs=N&year_id=2015&ccomp%5B1%5D=gt&cval%5B1%5D=100&cstat%5B1%5D=mp&game_month=0&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99'
df = pd.read_html(url)
print(df)
```